# How to import data from the file after one string and before another string?

Tags: import, data

Consider a file `file.dat` that has a form

```
...
string 1
x1 y1 z1
x2 y2 z2
...
string 2
...
```

where x,y,z are numbers.

Could you please tell me how to import only the following strings in the form of numerical data?

```
x1 y1 z1
x2 y2 z2
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is

```
str = Import["file.dat", "Text"];
data = StringCases[str, "string 1\n" ~~ x___ ~~ "\nstring 2" :>
    ImportString[x, "Table"]]
```

This example includes the newline character explicitly.  You may or may not want to include one before the first "string" and after the "2".  Or, you may want to leave the newline out.  Note that some text files may terminate the lines with "\r\n" instead of just the "\n".

Comment: `:> ImportString[x, "Table"]` or something I guess since OP asked to import the numbers "in the form of numerical data".

Comment: Good catch, @C.E.  Many thanks.